# How do I figure out the number of concurrent connections?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008-r2, connections

Our server architecture is as follows:

- Windows 2008 Server RC2
- WampServer with Apache 2, PHP 5, MySQL 5
- Dedicated connection hits firewall, which is routed to a single web server with multiple vhosts each on their own IP

We are now upgrading this infrastructure to something more scalable as we grow. One thing we're looking at is cloud. Obviously cloud computing can be tricky to transition to, especially for a small company like ours, as there seems to be hidden costs everywhere.

One thing we are trying to figure out is how many concurrent connections there are made to our server. Our potential new provider charges a set amount for every 100 connections per hour averaged over the month. What is the best way to work this out?

Comment: You don't have any metrics? Your firewall should give some information if it's anything worth the money.

Comment: Ask your prospective supplier how they calculate it - it will help you do the same.

Comment: @NathanC We have a m0n0wall firewall - the only thing I see in there is a traffic shaper that runs for the last 120 seconds with no configuration options.

Comment: @Iain The prospective supplier measure it on their load balancers, we don't have anything like the same setup we will be and also there's the windows -> linux change that doesn't help either

Comment: How do they count it though ?

Comment: If you mean how it's calculated, then it's the average number of connections per hour spread over the period of a month.